# How can I create a field in Firestore via REST calls

Tags: rest, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Suppose the ID of my project is **test-abcd** and the web key is **xyz**. The database is in test mode.

I have a simple database structure:

```
users | Paris | admin : "123456"
```

I would like to add a field `robin : "abc123"` inside `Paris`, so the result would be

```
users | Paris | admin : "123456"
      |       | robin : "abc123"
```

I'm trying to do a PATCH in the link

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/document.name=projects/test-abcd/databases/(default)/documents/users/Paris/robin/abc123?key=xyz
```

but it creates a collection and a document instead of a field:

```
users | Paris | admin : "123456"
      |       |
      |       | robin            | abc123 |
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It might help if you share the response that indicates that it didn't work, because it should give you some indication what went wrong.

Comment: And, if you're trying to update a document, the documentation suggests this is what you want to use: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/patch

Comment: Would it be `PATCH https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/document.name=projects/test-abcd/databases/(default)/documents/users/Paris/robin/abc123?key=xyz`?

Comment: @DougStevenson the thing I've said just worked, but it created a collection `robin` with a document `abc123` instead of a field `{robin : abc123}`, how can I fix it?

Comment: I suggest reading that page of docs again. You don't put the literal string "document.name" in the URL. It's just a way of specifying the named parameter from what follows in the "path parameters" section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to already mentioned [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/patch) in HTTP request patch you have to add path to document in the Firestore, update mask  and the key.

The field you want to add should be in request body. For example when you are using `curl` for the request, you have to add option `--data` with parameter:

```
--data '{"name":"","fields":{"robin":{"stringValue":"abc12345"}}}'
```

Funny thing is that, according to my tests, `name` in body, has to be included, however it does not matter what value it is :), so I left it as empty.

I suggest to use nice tool available on mentioned documentation. On the right side of the page there is "Try this API" feature that you can maximize clicking on the square icon ([direct link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/patch?apix=true)), that is helping to create the request in 3 formats (curl, HTTP and JS). You just need to provide details and the request command will be created. You can easily test created commands there.

I have used it and curl command working on my side is:

```
curl --request PATCH \
  'https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-test-project/databases/(default)/documents/users/Paris?updateMask.fieldPaths=robin&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"name":"","fields":{"robin":{"stringValue":"abc12345"}}}' \
  --compressed
```

Comment: I didn't need to use this `name` inside the json, but it worked anyway. Thanks!